# How to correct the error ts2590 other than disabling typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am currently trying to create a React Hook that returns a CSS style object with a few properties. But the error appears and I don't know why, but I suppose it is because the object is too complex to be evaluated, or am I completely wrong?

Error Message

> Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent. ts(2590)

```js
import React from 'react';

interface Test {
    color?: string;
    backgroundColor?: string;
    border?: string;
}

export const func = (prop: Test): React.CSSProperties => {
    const result: React.CSSProperties = {};

    for (const some in prop) {
        const key = some as keyof Test;
        result[key] = prop[key]; // Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent. ts(2590)
    }

    return result;
};
```

If the Test interface has only one or two properties, no problem appear. But with 3 or more, there is the error. Although the react app runs normally, and even the returned result when applied shows the correct styles. It's annoying and I can just ignore, but I would like to understand why this is happening and if there is a way to resolve it other than disable typescript for that line.

PS: The project was created using Vite and is running on `React v18` and `Typescript v4.6.3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
interface Test {
  color?: string;
  backgroundColor?: string;
  border?: string;
}

type TestKey = keyof Test;

export function func<T extends CSSProperties>(property: T): T {
  const result = {} as T;

  // eslint-disable-next-line guard-for-in
  for (const some in property) {
    const key = some as keyof T;
    result[key] = property[key];
  }

  return result;
}
```

As I understand it, the problem is that the Test interface doesn't have exactly the same origin as CSSProperties, even though it looks like it does... By creating a generic function, I was able to force this, since we were able to extend Test as being CSSProperties